# can't create a razor page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to create new pages for my app in ASP.NET razor pages, but I can't see anything
trying to open it

I'm right clicking on the folder then clicking add,
then I'm clicking Razor Page and getting to [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjFma.png)

then I click add and get to [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo8xG.png)

and here is where I'm getting stuck, because in that page there is no option to use Razor Pages.

is there any thing I'm doing wrong?

thank you.

Comment: this still doesn't work, It's still bringing me to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

When I choose Add=>Razor Page,I will get:
[image]

And when  I choose Add=>New Item,I will get:
[image]
Maybe you can try to choose Add=>New Scaffolded Item,then select Razor Page in the menu:
[image]